# Функции для подсчета символов в тексте, выделения последних букв

Tags: скрипт, php, функции

Хотела бы попытаться написать php скрипт для генератора тостов, стихов. Не подскажете ли функцию для подсчета символов в тексте и есть ли какая-нибудь функция, чтобы выделяла две последние буквы в тексте и искала по базе текст с такими же буквами в конце (для рифмы). Спасибо. И вообще, под силу ли начинающему программисту написать такое?

Comment: http://www.randomhaiku.com/

Comment: http://xenon.stanford.edu/~esincoff/poetry/jpoetry.html вот еще на Java. Для генерации текста используйте цепи Маркова.

Comment: вот еще на Java// Как раз для начинающего PHPшника.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strlen($str)` - подсчитывает длину строки

`substr($str,-2,2)` - возвращает последние два символа

Answer (score 2):

```
//считаем символы в тексте:
$count = strlen($text);

//считаем символы в тексте без букв:
$text = preg_replace('/[а-яА-ЯёЁ]*/u','',$text);
$count1 = strlen($text);

//Разность - число букв в тексте:
$countLetters = $count-$count1;
```

Код не самый оптимальный, но один из самых понятных.

По поводу рифмы: начинающий программист сможет написать рифмы только что-то типа "меня-любя, палка-селедка"... Вам придется в любом случае загонять громадный словарь и почти вручную выделять в каждом слове конец.

Функция называется

```
substr('Слово',/*начало*/0,/*конец*/-3);// вырежет 3 символа с конца.
```

Минус три - это как раз говорит, что вырезаются символы с конца.

Answer (score 2):

На PHP это сделать очень даже не сложно. PHP, как минимум, для этого и предназначен, хе-хе)
**Вообщем, смотрите доки:**

```
mb_strlen($string) // вычисление длины строки, учитывая набор символов, входящих в строку, т.е её кодировку.

strlen($string) // вычисление длины строки без учета её кодировки
```

Опираясь на это( ну и еще одну функцию ) можно легко получить две последние буквы любой текстовой строки:

```
$string = "1234567890";
$substr = mb_substr($string,-2,2,"UTF-8");
echo '<br>'.$substr;
```